# Manifest of library is not merged with the final manifest file

Tags: basic4android

Recently I have created a **library that does somethings using content providers**.
I **made a wrapper of that for B4A**.
 The problem is **it's content providers are not invoked when the app starts** (as they should).

When I look at the final manifest I see that the **manifest content of the library is not merged with the final manifest**.
I made a function to make sure library files and variables are readable within the basic code and they are.

**My question is** *Will the manifest of libraries be merged with the app manifest or I have to add them myself?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read, **Basic4Android (B4A) will not merge library manifests**.
So this means the **developer has to do it by himself**.

If you have a library that has some `AndroidManifest` contents, ***you must add all of them into the manifest editor*** (some of them can be added using the wrapper jar file).